# How to treat single line breaks as <br> in showdown?

Tags: markdown, showdown

How to have GitHub style treating of newlines using showdown?

I have tried an extension that does something like:

```
return text.replace(/[ ]*\n/g, "<br />\n")
```

It works in some cases but breaks lists for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay so I came up with extension which does that.

```
/**
 * Showdown extension for GFM newlines.
 * 
 * In very clear cases, let newlines become <br/> tags.
 *
 * This implementation is adopted from showdown-ghost.
 *
 */
(function () {
    var newline = function () {
        return [{
            type: 'lang',
            filter: function(text) {
                return text.replace(/^( *(\d+\.  {1,4}|[\w\<\'\">\-*+])[^\n]*)\n{1}(?!\n| *\d+\. {1,4}| *[-*+] +|#|$)/gm, function(e) {
                    return e.trim() + "  \n";
                })
            }
        }];
    };

    if (window.showdown) {
        window.showdown.extensions.newline = newline;
    }
})();
```

This is working great for me, although the regex is not 100% tested and will probably fail in some rare cases, so consider yourself warned.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe helpful for future readers. Showdown now has an option to do that.

```js
converter.setOption('simpleLineBreaks', true);
```

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for this great extension. It was very helpful for one of my projects.

It looks like this way of defining extensions is [deprecated now](https://github.com/showdownjs/showdown/issues/224). Since they didn't update the documentation yet I used the prettify extension as a template to update the extension you wrote to the new way of writing extensions in showdown:

```
(function (extension) {
  'use strict';

  if (typeof showdown !== 'undefined') {
    extension(showdown);
  } else if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    define(['showdown'], extension);
  } else if (typeof exports === 'object') {
    module.exports = extension(require('showdown'));
  } else {
    throw Error('Could not find showdown library');
  }

}(function(showdown){
  'use strict';
  showdown.extension('newline', function() {
    return [{
      type: 'lang',
      filter: function(text) {
        return text.replace(/^( *(\d+\.  {1,4}|[\w\<\'\">\-*+])[^\n]*)\n{1}(?!\n| *\d+\. {1,4}| *[-*+] +|#|$)/gm, function(e) {
          return e.trim() + "  \n";
        });
      }
    }];
  })
}));
```